# SSH connection requests password before password can be sent

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I have an odd problem I am trying to ssh connect to a remote device inside of a script so I can send commands to it but weirdly it's asking for the password to the ssh connection before I can even call an expect command. My snippet is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set PASS="password"
echo {$PASS}
ssh admin@10.3.0.1 -p 4118   #Firewall Device IP
expect {
"Password: "    
{send '$PASS\r'}
}
```

and the output I get is this:

```
password
Password:
```

I have no idea why it behaving this way.

Edit:
I've applied the changes suggested by @glenn jackman, the new code being:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set PASS "peak1234"
    puts "$PASS"
    ssh admin@10.3.0.1 -p 4118   #Firewall Device IP
    expect "Password :"    
    send "$PASS\r"
```

with these changes I get the error:

```
    set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

Comment: learn a bit tcl, otherwise it will be too tough for you to work with expect properly.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing expect with sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set PASS "password"        ; ## no "="
puts $PASS                 ; ## no "echo", braces wrong
ssh admin@10.3.0.1 -p 4118
expect "Password: " 
send "$PASS\r"             ; ## single quotes have no meaning in expect/Tcl
```

Comment: You would benefit from the Tcl tutorial: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested but I get the error `set: Variable name must begin with a letter.`

Comment: Then you did not apply my suggestions. Please show your code.